# Django 2 Test response for valid and invalid form

Tags: django, unit-testing

I made a `TestCase` to check if I would get the proper response and page redirection, but It's not working as I thought it would. When I tried a valid form I got the response I expected, but when I made it invalid, I still got the same response.

views.py (I left off the 'GET' 'else:')

```
def create_employee_profile(request):

if request.POST:
    name_form = EmployeeNameForm(request.POST)

    if name_form.is_valid():
        new_name_form = name_form.save()
        return redirect(new_name_form)

    else:
        return render(request,
                'service/create_or_update_profile.html',
                    {'name_form': name_form}
                    )
```

Test.py

```
class TestCreateEmployeeProfileView(TestCase):

def test_redirect_on_success(self):
    response = self.client.post('/service/', {
                'first_name': 'Test',    # Required
                'middile_name': 'Testy', # Optional
                'last_name': '',         # Required
                })

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

I guess while I am question, I might as well ask how to access the `redirect` to test that as well.

On success, the new path should be `/service/name/1/`, the '1' being the 'pk' of the created object.

I know I've seen `SimpleTestCase`, but I haven't found a good example or tutorial on how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always get a 200, that is because your form is *always* invalid. Your view redirects on successful save, which is a 302.

The way to test that the form has saved is to check that the new item is indeed in the database:

```
self.assertTrue(Employee.objects.filter(first_name='Testy').exists())
```

or whatever.

Comment: Is there a way to test that the redirect takes me to the expected URL? @daniel

Comment: You can use the [`assertRedirects`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.assertRedirects) method.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are two scenarios:**

1. Your form is valid, it will be saved and will be redirected to `new_name_form` that means a successful redirection. Since it is a successful redirection, you will get status code 200.
2. The same thing will happen when your form is invalid, i.e it will start rendering the `create_or_update_profile` page. Hence successful rendering and 200 status code.

So in either way, you will get successful redirection.

*If you want to check the form, this is the better approach to do:*

```
from form import EmployeeNameForm

class TestCreateEmployeeProfileView(TestCase):

    def test_redirect_on_success(self):
        form = UserForm(data='first_name': 'Test',    # Required
                'middile_name': 'Testy', # Optional
                'last_name': '',)
        self.assertTrue(form.is_valid())

    def test_redirect_on_failure(self):
        form = UserForm(data='first_name': 'Test',    # Required
                'middile_name': 'Testy', # Optional
                'last_name': '',)
        self.assertFalse(form.is_valid())
```

There will be no need to test the redirection. It surely will work fine, if the form is valid.

Hope that helped.

Comment: how can I test that redirect is going to the URL that I want it to?